# BeautifulSoup : Web scraping information after submit button is clicked

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to python coding, and i'm currently trying to extract data from a website but the information only shows up after a submit button is clicked. The webpage is https://www.ccq.org/fr-CA/qualification-acces-industrie/bassins-main-oeuvre/etat-bassins-main-oeuvre

Button I have to click : [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBTJB.jpg)

When I inspect the website, I was able to retrieve the url of the information contained/displayed after the button click (through the network tab when inspecting website).
Here is a preview of the information output the button URL gives : [info output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G6DH.jpg)

What i'd like to know is if it's possible to keep the information classified by DIV elements, like it does when I click the button on the site... Thank you!

Code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = "https://www.ccq.org/fr-CA/qualification-acces-industrie/bassins-main-oeuvre/etat- 
bassins-main-oeuvre"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,features="html.parser")

btn4 = soup.find('button',{"id":"get-labourpools"})
btn4_click = btn4['onclick']
```

Comment: If you have to *click a button* then `BeautifulSoup` is a poor choice. You'll need to explore [selenium](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an endpoint you can query to get the table data you're after.

Here's how:

```py
import json

import requests

region_id = "01"
occupation_id = "110"
url = f"https://www.ccq.org/api/labourpools?regionId={region_id}&occupationId={occupation_id}"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "01",
    "Name": "Iles de la Madeleine",
    "Occupations": [
      {
        "Id": "110",
        "Name": "Briqueteur-ma\u00e7on",
        "Pool": {
          "IsOpen": true,
          "IsLessThan10": true,
          "IsLessThan30": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "EffectiveDate": "17 janvier 2022"
  }
]
```

EDIT:

And if you want to get all tables for all regions and occupations, you can create all possible API request urls and get the data.

Here's how:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.ccq.org/fr-CA/qualification-acces-industrie/bassins-main-oeuvre/etat-bassins-main-oeuvre"
api_url = "https://www.ccq.org/api/labourpools?"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}


def get_ids(id_value: str) -> list:
    return [
        i["value"] for i
        in soup.find("select", {"id": id_value}).find_all("option")[1:]
    ]


with requests.Session() as session:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(base_url, headers=headers).text, "lxml")
    region_ids = get_ids("dropdown-region")
    occupation_ids = get_ids("dropdown-occupation")

all_query_urls = [
    f"{api_url}regionId={region_id}&occupationId={occupation_id}"
    for region_id in region_ids for occupation_id in occupation_ids
]

for query_url in all_query_urls[:2]:  # remove [:2] to get all combinations
    data = session.get(query_url, headers=headers).json()
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

This should output two entries:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "01",
    "Name": "Iles de la Madeleine",
    "Occupations": [
      {
        "Id": "110",
        "Name": "Briqueteur-ma\u00e7on",
        "Pool": {
          "IsOpen": true,
          "IsLessThan10": true,
          "IsLessThan30": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "EffectiveDate": "17 janvier 2022"
  }
]
[
  {
    "Id": "01",
    "Name": "Iles de la Madeleine",
    "Occupations": [
      {
        "Id": "130",
        "Name": "Calorifugeur",
        "Pool": {
          "IsOpen": true,
          "IsLessThan10": true,
          "IsLessThan30": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "EffectiveDate": "17 janvier 2022"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Some things are better left to http libs. Nice response!